# how to Create boolean from a text automatically with Neural networks and python

Tags: python, neural-network, nlp, boolean, data-science

I have couple of sentences in a text file something like below.

```
1) Must have bread and jam in the basket 
2) May contain any fruits like (orange, apple, grapes,etc.,)
```

and now i would like to get output like

```
1) brean AND jam
2) orange OR apple OR grapes
```

with the help of neural network it should understand the sentences and could able to give output as shown

is there any method? or research paper i could refer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an artificial neural network(ANN) to perform this task. An ANN is capable of performing at much harder problems and it requires much more data and computing power to train the model.

I think you are looking for a named entity recognizer(NER). It is able to extract entities like people, locations, organizations and other entities as well.

Take a look at [Stanford NER](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tag.html#module-nltk.tag.stanford).